# Vuetify - v-text-field (type="number") - set null instead of empty string

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm having a problem that `v-text-field` with `type="number"` attr sets it's value to empty string after it's cleared manually. I need it to return `null` in such cases.

Is there an attribute like `:clear-value="null"` ?

I can't find anything in the docs: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#props

Comment: You will have to use the computed property to manually set the v-model to null when the v-model becomes empty

Comment: It looks like it's already null. https://jsfiddle.net/0twoL593/

Answer (score 7):

Given that v-model is [shorthand for combining v-bind:value & v-on:input](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components), the best workaround I could come up with was splitting up v-model into separate v-bind:value and v-on:input properties.

For the v-on:input property, we can coerce the value to null.

So, given an existing field like this:

```
<v-text-field 
  type="number"
  v-model="myValue"
></v-text-field>
```

It can be changed to this:

```
<v-text-field
  type="number" 
  :value="myValue" 
  @input="myValue = $event !== '' ? $event : null"
></v-text-field>
```

Comment: I've been doing it like this as well, and I can attest to it working well... still, feels like this should've been baked into vuetify...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`watch`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) and watch for the value when it is changed to an empty string then replace it with null. However, this will always return null if you clear the textfield using the 'x' button, or when you empty the textfield manually.

```html
<v-textfield v-model="myValue" ... />
```

```js
// script

data() {
  return {
    myValue: 1
  }
},
watch: {
  myValue(newVal){
    if(newVal === '') {
      this.myValue = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@click:clear` event...

```
   v-text-field
    v-model="myValue"
    clearable
    @click:clear="setItNull()"
    type="number">
   </v-text-field>
```

Bind it to a method that set the value to null...

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data() {
        return {
            myValue: 1
        }
    },
    methods: {
      setItNull () {
          this.myValue === null
      },
    },
})
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/OeIqFYT8SG)